# How do I prevent RichTextBox from jumping to the top of the document when links are clicked?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-5

As part of my GUI in C# (.Net 5.0) I'm using the RichTextBox control (part of System.Windows.Forms) to display text and clickable links. My problem is when I click any links included without the form first having focus the act of clicking a link also focuses the textbox which automatically places the caret at the start of the text, this has the effect of making the textbox jump (or scroll) to the very top of document, losing one's position.

For my particular problem, the RichTextBox classes are assigned to TabPages within a TabControl- and all three of these components are created in response to user interaction (I understood the creation of these at runtime might limit the types of event handling available to me).

I've defined the RichTextBox control with multiline and both horizontal and vertical scrollbars, and to enable clickable links I'm using the `DetectUrls` option. Here is the full list of properties being used.

```cs
var control = new RichTextBox();
control.DetectUrls = true;
control.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
control.Multiline = true;
control.ReadOnly = true;
control.WordWrap = false;
control.Text = myContent; // large content filling multiple screens
control.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.Both;
control.LinkClicked += new LinkClickedEventHandler(RichTextBoxLinkClicked);
```

I've included the LinkClicked because I want to provide some interaction for the user, but whether this handler is assigned or not doesn't seem to influence the problem.

**Edit1** I came up with a solution that works to some extent; it prevents the scrolling by placing the caret at the beginning of the link (It doesn't work well though if there are more than one of the same link)

```cs
private void RichTextBoxLinkClicked(object sender, LinkClickedEventArgs e) {
  int caret = ((RichTextBox) sender).Text.IndexOf(e.LinkText);
  SelectionStart = caret;
}
```

**Edit2** A second solution that I found is to set the focus of the text-box on a `MouseEnter` event. I've come to think the key to the problem is to set the focus of the text boxes before any user interaction takes place, but I'm having problems finding a satisfactory way to achieve it.

Comment: Just set the focus on each RTB you want not to scroll on first activation, in the `OnShown()` override, for example; setting the focus, each control will receive a `WM_IME_SETCONTEXT` message and reflect `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_MOUSEMOVE` (the same happens the first time you select the Control when the container Form is not active). -- Note that the scroll-to-origin effect occurs just once (if you try again, it won't happen, because those messages have already been processed). Also, this happens just because you select the Control, no matter if the RTB contains a link or not.

Comment: @Jimi many thanks for your comment, this sounds like a good idea, however I'm not sure I can focus on my text-boxes through the form's OnShown event because I create them after the application has started. They are assigned to tabs, within a TabControl. I tried calling tab.Focus() when creating them but this doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: Add this in the `Selected` handler of your TabControl: `BeginInvoke(new Action(() => e.TabPage.Controls.OfType<RichTextBox>().ToList().ForEach(rtb => rtb.Focus())));`. -- You can also use SendMessage, calling it right after you have added your RTB to a TabPage: e.g., `SendMessage(control.Handle, WM_SETFOCUS, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);` -- BTW, *They are assigned to tabs, within a TabControl* is not exactly an information that you should provide in comments, it should probably be the first line in the body of your question. In bold.

Comment: Yea agree on including the TabControl context in the question, but I didn't actually understand it was relevant. Your solution kind of works by the way, but I should probably also point out that I am also creating the TabControl itself. This means in some cases when I create a TabControl with a single tab, the Selected event doesn't seem to get triggered on the first tab. (it is already selected at creation but the selected event isn't called)

Comment: It doesn't matter. As described, you can use SendMessage to send `WM_SETFOCUS` to the RTB you have just created, after you have added it to a TabPage.

Comment: ok right, I haven't tried the SendMessage part yet, many thanks. (Note my replies are not very immediate because I'm still trying to to get to grips with the offical docs - but all much appreciated, thank you)

Comment: All right. My time is up now. If you find the suggestion useful, post an answer yourself. Maybe I'll add a couple of notes later, to explain what's going on there.